# Error during silent install Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

When I execute a PowerShell script to do a silent install of Azure PowerShell it throws this exception:

> Exception calling "DownloadInstallerFile" with "2" argument(s): "The InstallerContext passed to this method requires a 
>   non-Null InstallerFile."
>   At line:18 char:5

Script follows:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller") | Out-Null

$ProductManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager
$ProductManager.Load()
$product = $ProductManager.Products | Where { $_.ProductId -eq "WindowsAzurePowerShell" }

$InstallManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.InstallManager

$Language = $ProductManager.GetLanguage("en")
$installertouse = $product.GetInstaller($Language)

$installer = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.Installer]'
$installer.Add($installertouse)
$InstallManager.Load($installer)

$failureReason=$null
foreach ($installerContext in $InstallManager.InstallerContexts) {
    $InstallManager.DownloadInstallerFile($installerContext, [ref]$failureReason)
}
$InstallManager.StartInstallation()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell doesn't install AzurePowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040261/powershell-doesnt-install-azurepowershell)